# How to set a multiple alert/reminder for the same calendar event?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

Using Calendar.app I can add an event and then add an alert to it, and set when the alert should be. But I only seem to be able to add one alert per event.

How can I give myself a repeating reminder of an upcoming event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: [Set event alerts and receive notifications in Calendar on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/set-event-alerts-and-receive-notifications-icl1012/mac)

Particularly step 3.

> ### Set an alert for an event
>
> 1. In the Calendar app [image] on your Mac, double-click or [force click](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/aside/glosb234ba05/11.0/mac/11.0) an event to view event details, then click the event’s time.
> 2. Click the Alert pop-up menu, then do one of the following:
>
> - Choose a time or day.
> - Choose Time to Leave. This option only applies if you added a location. For information about how time to leave is calculated, see
>   [Add a location](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/add-location-and-travel-time-to-events-icl43600/11.0/mac/11.0#icl464f2de72).
> - Choose Custom, then choose an option:
>
>   - Message with sound: Displays a notification on the screen and makes a sound.
>   - Email: Sends you an email.
>   - Open file: Opens the file you choose.
>
> 3. To add another alert, place the pointer over the Alert pop-up menu, then click the Add button. [image]
>
> You can set only one alert for Exchange events.
>
> To remove an alert, click the Alert menu, then choose None.

[image]

Comment: this seems to be only *some* calenders ;(

The Outlook /Exchange calendars does not have that circled plus sign next to alerts ;(

Got bitten by that today (12.5) as the Google Clandars seems to have that plus, not my hosted Exchange work email/calendar ;(